# Matrix union in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, spatial-join, digital-image-processing, change-detection

How can I do matrix processing in ArcGIS or ERDAS Imagine?
l have two different raster images for change detection. Matrix join same code filed information.[image]

In this video link already done matrix in ERDAS and then process continue in ArcGIS.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qg3xE_YAgWA&t=519s

[image]

Comment: See if combine tool does what you want.

Comment: l checkec combine, combine or, combine xor and combinatorial and. None of all didn't give that table when calculate.

Comment: Combine tool does not have this options http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/combine.htm